# RESTful HTTP GET not response is null iOS

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have the following code below and for some reason I am getting a nil response when it executes. I have manually tried the link in the browser and it prints JSON data. I know there is something I'm doing wrong but I haven't been able to spot it. What am I missing?

```
        NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://localhost/getData?usersesh=%@&dev=%@&lat=%f&long=%f", sessionId, deviceName, coordLat, coordLong];

        NSString *strFormattedUrl = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
        NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:strFormattedUrl];

        NSLog(@"url: %@",strFormattedUrl);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        //[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        //[request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSLog(@"response: %@",response);
        NSLog(@"%@",strUrl);


        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSMutableDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                             JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                             error:&error];

            didReturnError = [jsonData[@"ERROR"] integerValue];
            if(!didReturnError){
                NSMutableDictionary *respBody = [jsonData objectForKey:@"RESPONSE_BODY"];
                eventCount = [respBody[@"EVENTS"] count];
```

...

Comment: Actually a localhost URL? And then where are you running it?

Comment: No, I simply threw that in there as to not reveal the actual URL. I'm running this on a separate network. The POST requests I've made work fine. I'm doing something wrong with my GET requests.

Comment: Best to make it obvious where you make changes like that or you'll get false positive answers. What is the response and errors?

Comment: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x7ff871d39720 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff871d5b700 "The network connection was lost.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=the_formatted_url_here

Comment: After resetting the sim, the -1005 error code disappeared. Now I get a 200 response code. It seems like the request is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to restart the iOS simulator as it had lost internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the line below:

`NSString *strFormattedUrl = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];`

with this:

`NSString *strFormattedUrl = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`